# IntelliTest does not use PexArguments

Tags: unit-testing, pex, intellitest

I am trying to force `IntelliTest` to try specific parameters with the following code:

```
[PexClass]
public class Program {
    [PexMethod]
    [PexArguments((short)1234, "G", Alternate = true)]
    public string Format(short val, string format) {
        return val.ToString(format);
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea what 1234 and "G" are never tried?

Code on [pex4fun](http://pex4fun.com/default.aspx?language=CSharp&code=bQGFjk1rwzAMhu%2f_FaKnBEKg7W5hhzJoT4VCyi6jBy9VU1PHKpK8D0r%2f_5y0y9ipQgdLz%2fvYjuJCC%2fW3KHaVicO0dg2T0EHLDX6VS7YdfhKfHuCyRtXE5VHu1Xq3t_ooVMYYeEv0xVuRnTnHd_8aaPoJNkxtcuCSMpD6Vn16jXqk%2fe7fbsFt7DCoZJkciTWfzuZPBUxWkwIWXpGDVYRnUI6Y%2f6n3F0W5%2f%2fGSuLN6uwA_rC9_wWEA_ahdxtNQjBo59Ea5pXpQsrtSjcmruf4A)

Thank you, Rok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternating input enumerators is not supported yet. Either remove *Alternate=true*, or set it to *false*, and then 1234, "G" will get used.